# Getting Data from REST Api

Tags: android, node.js, spring, web-services, rest

I have a node.js application with an Angular Webfrontend and an Android App connecting to the backend via rest. Now I'm not sure how to return objects from node to the clients:

**Way 1:**

```
res.send(req.user);
```

If I'll do it like this I can load the user object from angular like:

```
return $http.post('/api/login', user)
  .success(function (data) {
  $rootScope.currentUser = data;
```

and in my Android app (simplyfied call, I use Spring and Gson):

```
user = SpringRestTemplate.getRestTemplate().postForObject(Routes.getLogin(), user, User.class);
```

This works fine, but what I actually would like to return from node would be my

**Way 2:**

```
res.send({user: req.user });
```

for angular everything pretty much stays the same:

```
$rootScope.currentUser = data.user;
```

but for android I didn't found any other way than to write the json conversion myself:

```
ResponseEntity<Map> map = SpringRestTemplate.getRestTemplate().postForEntity(Routes.getLogin(), dUser, Map.class);
LinkedTreeMap<String, User> map2 = (LinkedTreeMap<String, User>) map.getBody();
Map ltm = (Map) map.get("user");

String id = (String) ltm.get("_id");
String userName = (String) ltm.get("userName");
// ... and so on
```

I get, why this is the case (except why I had to use a second map), but I wonder if there's any simplier way to achieve my second way.

I left the Models and the SpringRestTemplate Code out, since this is more a general question on how to handle JSON with the following structure:

```
{ user : { _id: "1", userName: "foo", ...}}
```

Any guidance on how to deal with this problem would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simplified, but this will solve your issue.

1. Create a POJO that matches the JSON Schema using [Json Schema to POJO](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)
2. If you can, use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) or something more easily suited for Android to consume the API.
3. Create a retrofit service (look at the retrofit link above) and then connect to the API and you'll have a User object.

Option B: 
Use [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to deserialize your object into a POJO from your spring stuff. But I recommend using Retrofit or something similar as its easier and cleaner.

Comment: I usually just use apaches lib to make request and it works just fine. I don't think retro fit is even supported any longer. Its built on apache anyway

Comment: @HopeRunsDeep https://github.com/square/retrofit lastest commit 2 days ago at the time of writing this